# How to use django tags in next.js javascript file?

Tags: python, reactjs, django, next.js

I have a full stack application built in next.js as frontend and django as backend. The frontend is full next.js and react.

I want to use django tags in the javascript pages files. The code that i want to use is looking like this :

```
{% for item in items %}
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'item:detail' item.name %}">
                        <div>
                            <img alt="{{ item.name }}" src="{{ item.image.url }}" class="rounded-t-xl">
                        </div>

                        <div class="p-6 bg-white rounded-b-xl">
                            <h2 class="text-2xl">{{ item.name }}</h2>
                            <p class="text-gray-500">Price: {{ item.price }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Those are some information for an item that is stored in the database through django.

I checked another post from stackoverflow and said something like this

> You can't add any Django template code in js file directly.
>
> There are 3 ways you can add the first_name in js file.
>
> Write a django ajax views and call the api for first_name from your js file as soon as your page is loaded. or render your first name in
> your html file hidden input fields and than grab the fields value it's
> name or id from your jsfile or put a utill function on your html js
>
> tags which are gonna call you driver.js file related method.

I want to use the first option if possible someone could give me an example or a tutorial ?